# How to do a simple Google Cloud Trace request in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-trace

I am trying to perform a simple push traces operation to my Google Cloud Trace project and I simply can't seem to send data across.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-cloudtrace:v1-rev6-1.22.0'
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

And the following Java code with dummy info for the project ID and my secrets file:

```
package test;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.CloudTrace;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.CloudTraceScopes;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.Trace;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.TraceSpan;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.Traces;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(
                        new FileInputStream("/path/to/secrets.json"),
                        httpTransport,
                        jsonFactory)
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(CloudTraceScopes.TRACE_APPEND));

        CloudTrace gceTrace = new CloudTrace.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, cred)
                .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Trace test app")
                .build();

        TraceSpan span1 = new TraceSpan();
        span1.setName("test");
        span1.setStartTime(Long.toString(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()*1000000)+"Z");
        Trace trace = new Trace();
        trace.setSpans(Collections.singletonList(span1));
        Traces traces = new Traces();
        traces.setTraces(Collections.singletonList(trace));
        gceTrace.projects().patchTraces("myprojectid", traces).execute();
    }

}
```

I currently get the following error that contains no helpful indication except something seems to be wrong with my startTime value:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'traces.traces[0].spans[0].start_time' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Timestamp), Field 'startTime', Invalid time format: Failed to parse input",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'traces.traces[0].spans[0].start_time' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Timestamp), Field 'startTime', Invalid time format: Failed to parse input",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:44)
```

I have tried to replace the startTime with the following value:

```
span1.setStartTime("2016-08-04T01:00:00Z");
```

which gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:44)
```

I also tried adding a endTime with:

```
span1.setEndTime("2016-08-04T01:00:01Z");
```

which also gives me the same error.

I'm pretty much at a lost at what needs to be done as I cannot find a single working Java example for this.
Thank you in advance for any pointers for a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here's a working example with mandatory and optional fields pointed out.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-cloudtrace:v1-rev6-1.22.0'
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package test;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.CloudTrace;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.CloudTraceScopes;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.Trace;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.TraceSpan;
import com.google.api.services.cloudtrace.v1.model.Traces;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(
                        new FileInputStream("/path/to/secrets.json"),
                        httpTransport,
                        jsonFactory)
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(CloudTraceScopes.TRACE_APPEND));

        CloudTrace gceTrace = new CloudTrace.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, cred)
                .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Trace test app")
                .build();

        // They are optional
        Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<>();
        labels.put("key1", "val1");

        TraceSpan span = new TraceSpan();
        span.setSpanId(new BigInteger("1")); // Mandatory
        span.setName("test"); // Optional
        span.setKind("RPC_SERVER"); // Optional
        span.setStartTime("2016-08-04T01:00:00Z"); // Optional
        span.setEndTime("2016-08-04T01:00:01Z"); // Optional
        span.setLabels(labels); // Optional
        Trace trace = new Trace();
        trace.setProjectId("myprojectid"); // Mandatory
        trace.setTraceId("A096D4956A424EEB98AE7863505B1E1F"); // Mandatory
        trace.setSpans(Collections.singletonList(span)); // Mandatory
        Traces traces = new Traces();
        traces.setTraces(Collections.singletonList(trace)); // Mandatory
        gceTrace.projects().patchTraces("myprojectid", traces).execute();
    }

}
```

While some values are optional, like startTime or endTime, it makes sense to put something there.

I managed to put it together thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276720/using-google-cloud-trace-api) showing the expected values and looking at the REST API doc describing each field, especially for cryptic values like Trace ID:

- [patchTraces()](https://cloud.google.com/trace/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/patchTraces)
- [Trace and TraceSpan](https://cloud.google.com/trace/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.traces)

Comment: I got the code working but I could not find the trace in the Google Cloud Console . For example  https://console.cloud.google.com/traces/details/A096D4956A424EEB98AE7863505B1E1F?project=myprojectid it always says "Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.
"

Comment: The values themselves are only an example, you might want to adapt them, especially the Trace ID and the start/end time.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I changed to my ID and gave a time with 30 days so that its not expired. Still not showing up. Do you see any other problem or have any other working code? The execute() of last line returned a json with just project id I hope that meant sucess .